# Unable to run testcases in pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, pytest, appium-android

I am trying to use pytest framework for testing However when i run the command from the terminal  pytest test_Analysis.py -s -v it shows no test rans

Below are the snapshots for your reference.

[image]

Also if remove the constructor it run but gives me the error stating there is not driver attribute present

[image]

and if i keep the constructor it gives me an error as well
below is the error for your reference.

[image]

Comment: I was able to run it however i had to remove the constructor which i had created if remove the constructor it gives me an error stating that there is no driver attribute found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need constructor method. You can follow below approach.

```
class TestAnalysis:
    def test_navigate_to_analysis(self, apiuum_driver):
        analysis = appium_driver.find_element(By.ID, 'id name')
        analysis.click()
```

Instead of using `apium_fixture` from `pytest.mark`, you can refer it explicitly from the test method.